# Create jpg and insert into word document

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I'm starting to do my first drawing (jpg) with c#.
I'd like to insert it directly into a word document.

Could I do that without saving my jpg into a temporary directory?

in this moment, I can only load image from temp directory:

```
        public void InsertAPicture(string document, string fileName, string bookmarkName)
    {
        Paragraph newParag = null;

        using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument =
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;

            ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                imagePart.FeedData(stream);
            }

            newParag = AddImageToBody(wordprocessingDocument, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));

            replaceBookmarkText(wordprocessingDocument, bookmarkName, newParag);
        }
    }

    private Paragraph AddImageToBody(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string relationshipId)
    {
        // Define the reference of the image.
        var element =
             new Drawing(
                 new DW.Inline(
                     new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
                     new DW.EffectExtent()
                     {
                         LeftEdge = 0L,
                         TopEdge = 0L,
                         RightEdge = 0L,
                         BottomEdge = 0L
                     },
                     new DW.DocProperties()
                     {
                         Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                         Name = "Picture 1"
                     },
                     new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                         new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                     new A.Graphic(
                         new A.GraphicData(
                             new PIC.Picture(
                                 new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                     new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                     {
                                         Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                         Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                                     },
                                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                 new PIC.BlipFill(
                                     new A.Blip(
                                         new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                             new A.BlipExtension()
                                             {
                                                 Uri =
                                                   "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                             })
                                     )
                                     {
                                         Embed = relationshipId,
                                         CompressionState =
                                         A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                     },
                                     new A.Stretch(
                                         new A.FillRectangle())),
                                 new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                     new A.Transform2D(
                                         new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                         new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                                     new A.PresetGeometry(
                                         new A.AdjustValueList()
                                     ) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                         ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
                 )
                 {
                     DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     EditId = "50D07946"
                 });


        return new Paragraph(new Run(element));            
    }        

    private void replaceBookmarkText(WordprocessingDocument doc, string bookmarkName, Paragraph text)
    {
        var t = (from el in doc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<BookmarkStart>()
                 where (el.Name == bookmarkName) &&
                 (el.NextSibling<Run>() != null)
                 select el).First();

        t.NextSibling<Run>().Append(text);
    }
```

And, i create a graphic image in this way:

```
    Bitmap objBitmap;
Graphics objGraphics;

//Create object
objBitmap = new Bitmap(200, 5);
objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBitmap);
//Draw line
objGraphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), 0, 0, 200, 200);
//Save
objBitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

objGraphics.Dispose();
objBitmap.Dispose();
```

How can i send to my InsertAPicture Method, my Graphics object instead of my image path file?

Comment: how are you inserting it into the document? also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Show us what have u tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your image to a `MemoryStream`. Then pass that stream to `InsertAPicture` in place of the `fileName` parameter. Then read the stream instead of creating a `FileStream`

Comment: In that way i can insert the image, but It's corrupt. If I send the memoryStream directly into a file, it's correct, but it doesn't work if i send it to InsertAPicture.